# Idiomatically mock OpenURI.open_uri with Minitest

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

I have code that invokes `OpenURI.open_uri` and I want to confirm the URI being used in the call (so a stub isn't going to work for me), but also intercept the call.  I'm hoping not to have to abstract away the call to `OpenURI.open_uri` just for test purposes.  What I've come up with seems verbose and overly complicated.

*under_test.rb*

```
require 'open-uri'

class UnderTest
  def get_request(uri)
    open(uri).read
  end
end
```

*test_under_test.rb*

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './lib/under_test'

class TestUnderTest < Mintest::Test
  def test_get_request
    @under_test = UnderTest.new
    mock_json  = '{"json":[{"element":"value"}]}'
    uri = URI('https://www.example.com/api/v1.0?attr=value&format=json')
    tempfile = Tempfile.new('tempfile')
    tempfile.write(mock_json)

    mock_open_uri = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock_open_uri.expect(:call, tempfile, [uri])

    OpenURI.stub :open_uri, mock_open_uri do
      @under_test.get_request('https://www.example.com/api/v1.0?attr=value&format=json'
    end

    mock_open_uri.verify
  end
end
```

Am I misusing or misunderstanding Minitest's mocking?

Part of the dancing around is that I'm also creating a `Tempfile` so that my `read` call succeeds.  I could stub that out but I'm hoping there's a way I could head off the call chain closer to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, test-spies could be the way to go:

> A **test spy** is a function that records arguments, return value, the value of this and exception thrown (if any) for all its calls. A **test spy** can be an anonymous function or it can wrap an existing function.

*taken from: http://sinonjs.org/docs/*

For `Minitest` we can use gem [spy](https://github.com/ryanong/spy).

After [installing](https://github.com/ryanong/spy#installation), and [including](https://github.com/ryanong/spy#minitesttestunit) it in our test environment, the test can be rearranged as follows:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'spy/integration'
require 'ostruct' # (1)
require './lib/under_test'

class TestUnderTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_get_request
    mock_json = '{"json":[{"element":"value"}]}'
    test_uri = URI('https://www.example.com/api/v1.0?attr=value&format=json')

    open_spy = Spy.on_instance_method(Kernel, :open) # (2)
                  .and_return { OpenStruct.new(read: mock_json) } # (1)

    @under_test = UnderTest.new

    assert_equal @test_under.get_request(test_uri), mock_json
    assert open_spy.has_been_called_with?(test_uri) # (3)
  end
end
```

(1): Because of [*duck typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) nature of Ruby, you don't really need to provide in your tests exact objects that would be created in non-test run of your application.

Let's take a look at your `UnderTest` class:

```
class UnderTest
  def get_request(uri)
    open(uri).read
  end
end
```

In fact, `open` in "production" environment could return instance of `Tempfile`, which **quacks** with method `read`. However in your "test" environment, when *"stubbing"*, you don't need to provide "real" object of type `Tempfile`. It is enough, to provide *anything*, that **quacks** like one.

Here I used the power of [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html), to build *something*, that will respond to `read` message. Let's take a look at it closer:

```
require 'ostruct'
tempfile = OpenStruct.new(read: "Example output")
tempfile.read # => "Example output"
```

In our test case we're providing the *minimal* amount of code, to make the test pass. We don't care about other [`Tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) methods, because our tests rely only on `read`.

(2): We're creating a [spy](https://github.com/ryanong/spy#method-stubs) on `open` method in `Kernel` module, which might be confusing, because we're requiring `OpenURI` module. When we try:

```
Spy.on_instance_method(OpenURI, :open)
```

it throws exception, that the

```
NameError: undefined method `open' for module `OpenURI'
```

It turns that the `open` method is attached to mentioned `Kernel` module.

Additionally, we define what will be returned by method call with following code:

```
and_return { OpenStruct.new(read: mock_json) }
```

When our test script executes, the `@test_under.get_request(test_uri)` is performed, which registers the `open` method call with its *arguments* on our `spy` object. This is something thah we can assert by [(3)](https://github.com/ryanong/spy#method-spies).

**Test what can go wrong**

Ok, for now we've seen that our script proceeded without any problems, but I'd like to highlight the example of how assertion on our `spy` could fail.

Let's modify a bit the test:

```
class TestUnderTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_get_request
    open_spy = Spy.on_instance_method(Kernel, :open)
                  .and_return { OpenStruct.new(read: "whatever") }

    UnderTest.new.get_request("http://google.com")

    assert open_spy.has_been_called_with?("http://yahoo.com")
  end
end
```

Which when run, will fail with something similar to:

```
  1) Failure:
TestUnderTest#test_get_request [test/lib/test_under_test.rb:17]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

We have called our `get_request`, with "http://google.com", but asserting if `spy` registered call with "http://yahoo.com" argument.

This proves our `spy` works as expected.

It's quite long answer, but I tried to provide the best possible explanation, however I don't expect all things are clear - if you have any questions, I'm more than happy to help, and update the answer accordingly!

Good luck!

Comment: Dziękuję bardzo/Cheers @Pawel Dawczak for the thorough answer -- this also clears up some of the confusion I had around stubbing/mocking `OpenURI.open_uri` versus `Kernel.open`.

Comment: Cała przyjemność po mojej stronie/My pleasure :). Yes, it might be easier to think of it as, when requiring `open-uri` enriches `Kernel.open` method with capability of processing requests. If you performed `open("http://google.com")` without requiring `open-uri`, it would end up with `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://google.com`, but after requiring, the same thing does what expected `=> #<Tempfile:/var/folders/z0/kdcygzhj0cz40vvymknl52q80000gn/T/open-uri20150305-17560-1azpjax>`. And yes - it accepts `url` as a string, no need to wrap with `URI`

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a similar problem:

```
URI::HTTPS.any_instance.stubs(:open).returns(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

With new Rspec you can simply use:

```
allow(URI).to receive(:open).and_return(your_value)
```

In your code do

```
URI.open(link)
```

cause calling open directly on Kernel is not recommended.