# How to properly stub doubles

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stubbing, rspec3

Code being tested:

```
class Session
  def initialize
    @interface = Interface.new(self)
    @interface.hello
  end
end

class Interface
  def initialize(session, out = $STDOUT)
    @session = session
    @out = out
  end

  def hello
    @out.puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Test:

```
describe Session do
  let (:fake_stdout) {double("$STDOUT", :puts => true)}
  let (:interface) {instance_double("Interface", :out => "fake_stdout")}
  let (:session) { Session.new }

  describe "#new" do
    it "creates an instance of Session" do
      expect(session).to be_an_instance_of(Session)
    end
  end
end
```

This throws `private method 'puts' called for nil:NilClass`. It seems it's not seeing the `fake_stdout` with its specified `:puts` as `out`. I tried tying it with `allow(Interface).to receive(:new).with(session).and_return(interface)`, but that changed nothing. How do I get the tested `Session` class to see the double/instance double and pass the test?

Comment: problem is `@out.puts "hello"`.. do write `@out.send :puts, "hello"`.. Why? Read your exception, it is telling you. .:D

Comment: Can you please explain the `.send`? That's new to me, and not obvious in the exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby

Comment: That breaks `fake_stdout` such that it prints to the console and messes up the test suite output. It seems like `fake_stdout` isn't being tied in correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is not really problem with stubbing, but the general approach. When writing your unit tests for some class, you should stick to functionality of that class and eventually to API it sees. If you're stubbing "internal" `out` of `Interface` - it's already to much for specs of `Session`.

What `Session` really sees, is `Interface`s public `hello` method, thus `Session` spec, should not be aware of internal implementation of it (that it is `@out.puts "hello"`). The only thing you should really focus is that, the `hello` method has been called. On the other hand, ensuring that the `put` is called for `hello` should be described in specs for `Interface`.

Ufff... That's long introduction/explanation, but how to proceed then? (known as *show me the code!* too ;)).

Having said, that `Session.new` should be aware only of `Interface`s `hello` method, it should trust it works properly, and `Session`s spec should ensure that the method is called. For that, we'll use a `spy`. Let's get our hand dirty!

```
RSpec.describe Session do
  let(:fake_interface) { spy("interface") }
  let(:session)        { Session.new }

  before do
    allow(Interface).to receive(:new).and_return(fake_interface)
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "creates an instance of Session" do
      expect(session).to be_an_instance_of(Session) # this works now!
    end

    it "calls Interface's hello method when initialized" do
      Session.new
      expect(fake_interface).to have_received(:hello)
    end
  end
end
```

> A **test spy** is a function that records arguments, return value, the value of this and exception thrown (if any) for all its calls.

This is taken from [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) (which is the first result when googling for "what is test spy"), but explanation is accurate.

How does this work?

```
Session.new
expect(fake_interface).to have_received(:hello)
```

First of all, we're executing some code, and after that we're *asserting* that expected *things* happened. Conceptually, we want to be sure, that during `Session.new`, the `fake_interface` `have_received(:hello)`. That's all!

**Ok, but I need another test ensuring that `Interface`s method is called with *specific* argument**.

Ok, let's test that!

Assuming the `Session` looks like:

```
class Session
  def initialize
    @interface = Interface.new(self)
    @interface.hello
    @interface.say "Something More!"
  end
end
```

We want to test `say`:

```
RSpec.describe Session do
  describe "#new" do
    # rest of the code

    it "calls interface's say_something_more with specific string" do
      Session.new
      expect(fake_interface).to have_received(:say).with("Something More!")
    end
  end
end
```

This one is pretty straightforward.

**One more thing - my `Interface` takes a `Session` as an argument. How to test that the `interface` calls `session`s method?**

Let's take a look at sample implementation:

```
class Interface
  # rest of the code

  def do_something_to_session
    @session.a_session_method
  end
end

class Session
  # ...

  def another_method
    @interface.do_something_to_session
  end

  def a_session_method
    # some fancy code here
  end
end
```

It won't be much surprise, if I say...

```
RSpec.describe Session do
  # rest of the code

  describe "#do_something_to_session" do
    it "calls the a_session_method" do
      Session.new.another_method
      expect(fake_interface).to have_received(:do_something_to_session)
    end
  end
end
```

You should check, if `Session`s `another_method` called `interface`s `do_something_to_session` method.

If you test like this, you make the tests less fragile to future changes. You might change an implementation of `Interface`, that it doesn't rely on `put` any more. When such change is introduced - you have to update the tests of `Interface` only. `Session` knows only the proper method is called, but what happens inside? That's the `Interface`s job...

Hope that helps! Please, take a look at another example of `spy` in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813062/idiomatically-mock-openuri-open-uri-with-minitest/28878374#28878374).

Good luck!

Comment: While spies seem to be a stylistic choice (according to my understanding of the RSpec documentation), this is the first and the best explanation of stubbing I have seen in the RSpec 3.X vernacular. You are right that my approach is lacking (many changes have been made to that effect), but you would be helping a lot of people if you were to write this into some stand alone piece solely on stubbing with this level of context, detail, and explanation. I've been stuck on trying to make sense of stubbing for more than a month, and this is what made it click.